# pgfplots: Specifying colors in patch depending on value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I need to create a diagramm with pgfplots in which the color changes depending on the value of each mark, as shown in the following.

[image]

The best i could come up with, was something like this

[image]

using the code below.

```
\begin{axis}[colorbar,ymin=100,ymax=500,ytick={100,150,200,250,300,350,400,450,500},xmin=400,xmax=1200,xtick={400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200},]
    \addplot[
        patch,
        shader=interp,
        point meta=explicit,
    ]
    coordinates {
(400,100) [8.5]
%(600,200) [8.2]
%(700,300) [7.9]
(400,500) [8.1]
(1200,100) [7.1]    
};
\addplot[
color=black,
only marks,
mark=square*,
]coordinates {
(400,100)(400,150)(400,200)(400,250)(400,300)(400,350)(400,500)
(500,100)(500,150)(500,200)(500,250)(500,300)
(600,100)(600,150)(600,200)(600,250)(600,300)
(700,100)(700,150)(700,200)(700,250)(700,300)
(800,100)(800,150)(800,200)(800,250)
(900,100)(900,150)(900,200)(900,250)
(1000,100)(1000,150)(1000,200)
(1100,100)(1100,150)
(1200,100)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My problem is that each coordinate has a different value for which i would like to have a corresponding color. The code works fine for three coordinates, but as soon i add more coordinates, for example the commented one in the code, i recieve the following,

[image]

How could i recieve a diagramm like in the first picture, with more than three coordinates?

I would be very grateful for your help.

PS: This is my first post, please feel free to let me know how to improve my posts for the future

Comment: HI J2000.  It is not clear for me where in your code or lists (in general) can one find thee values which you are referring to.  In principle you need a list of points and for each point a corresponding value.  Having that, you can obtain a representation of the values in the plane of the points using different colours.